# Scrapy crawls but not scrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, scrapy

The problem is that if I add product url directly to "start_urls" everything works just fine. But when product page appear during crawl (all crawled pages returns '200') it doesn't scrape....
I'm running spider through:

```
scrape crawl site_products -t csv -o Site.csv
```

Spider code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from site.items import SiteItem
import datetime


class SiteProducts(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'site_products'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = [
        #'http://www.example.com/us/sweater_cod39636734fs.html',
        #'http://www.example.com/us/sweater_cod39693703uh.html',
        #'http://www.example.com/us/pantaloni-5-tasche_cod36883777uu.html',
        #'http://www.example.com/fr/robe_cod34663996xk.html',
        #'http://www.example.com/fr/trousers_cod36898044mj.html',
        'http://www.example.com/us/women/onlinestore/suits-and-jackets',
    ]

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.example.com/us/', 'http://www.example.com/fr/', )), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*_cod.*\.html', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = SiteItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//h2[@class="productName"]/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="priceValue"]/text()')[0].extract()
        if response.xpath('//span[@class="currency"]/text()')[0].extract() == '$':
            item['currency'] = 'USD'
        else:
            item['currency'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="currency"]/text()')[0].extract()
        item['category'] = response.xpath('//li[@class="selected leaf"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['sku'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="MFC"]/text()').extract()
        if response.xpath('//div[@class="soldOutButton"]/text()').extract() == True or response.xpath('//span[@class="outStock"]/text()').extract() == True:
            item['avaliability'] = 'No'
        else:
            item['avaliability'] = 'Yes'
        item['time'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")
        item['color'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id, "color_")]/a/text()').extract()
        item['size'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id, "sizew_")]/a/text()').extract()
        if '/us/' in response.url:
            item['region'] = 'US'
        elif '/fr/' in response.url:
            item['region'] = 'FR'
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="descriptionContent"]/text()')[0].extract()
        return item
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested and it seems that this website blocks all non-standard User-Agents (by returning 403). So try setting `user_agent` class paremeter to something common like:

```
class SiteProducts(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'site_products'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0'
```

or just set it in projects `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0'
```

You can find more user-agent strings around the web, e.g. [official mozzila docummentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

EDIT:
Upon further inspection I see that your LinkExtractor logic is faulty. Linkextractors extract in defined rule order and your extractors overflap, that means first linkextractor with follow also extract product pages as well which means the product link extractor you have will crawl pages that were already crawler previously and get dupe filtered.

You need to rework your first linkextractor to avoid product pages. You can do that just by copying the `allow` parameter from your linkextractor to `deny` parameter of your first linkextractor.

Comment: Already done that in settings.py. I'm getting Crawled (200) for all pages. But as I said above, I'm still getting 0 scrapes. But if i add product url to "start_urls" it will scrape that exact product just fine.

Comment: @LeonidIvanov I've tried your spider and it works however it seems your first linkextractor is blocking the product extraction, see my edit for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped! Lost almost whole day to figure out what's the problem is.... By the way it's 'deny' not 'disallow'.

Comment: @LeonidIvanov thanks, edited it. But yeah CrawlSpider can get a bit tricky at times so losing few hours debugging it is not unheard of. General rule of thumb is to inspect the log thoroughly. You can save spider log with `scrapy crawl myspider &> myspider.log` and log as much as possible in your spider with `logging` module.